# Use case of Artifact.getBaseVersion()

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

The [Artifact](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact.html) interface offers `getBaseVersion()`, besides `getVersion()`. The base version is set in `setBaseVersionInternal(String)`, as follows:

```
Matcher m = VERSION_FILE_PATTERN.matcher( baseVersion );

if ( m.matches() )
{
    this.baseVersion = m.group( 1 ) + "-" + SNAPSHOT_VERSION;
}
else
{
    this.baseVersion = baseVersion;
}
```

I am clueless with respect to the semantics of the two different version strings. When is the returned value of `getBaseVersion()` actually different from `getVersion()`, and why?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of SNAPSHOTs: unique and non-unique. The latter ends with `-SNAPSHOT` and is generated when you work with projects on your own system. A `mvn install` will copy the artifact with the -SNAPSHOT version to the local repository.

If you use SNAPSHOTs from a remote repository, then those artifacts are timestamped (ends with a human friendly representation of a timestamp), which makes them unique. This has to do with the way they are uploaded to the remote repository.

Comment: Thanks, but.. why `getBaseVersion()`? I suppose that `getVersion()` may be a "uniquified" version, including a timestamp, while `getBaseVersion()` always returns the version string as found in the POM?

Comment: When talking about maven-plugins, it just depends what they need. Most plugins are not interested in its unique value, but if it s a SNAPSHOT or not. In that case, you should use `getBaseVersion()`. When referring to the actual file, you probably need the `getVersion()`. An example: look at http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html should it respect the timestamp or not? Probably not, you just want to know if it is the same SNAPSHOT or not.